# Select elements with specific class in specific div

Tags: css, css-selectors

Lets say I have a div with class DIVCLASS, and I have elements with class ELEMENTCLASS. How can I select all elements with class: ELEMENTCLASS that are in divs with class: DIVCLASS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends,

Does it matter at which level ELEMENTCLASS is situated in DIVCLASS?

If not, use:

```
.divclass .elementclass {
    //properties here
}
```

If you only want to select ELEMENTCLASS that are *direct descendants* of DIVCLASS, use:

```
.divclass > .elementclass {
    //properties here
}
```

Don't overspecify by using div.divclass unless it's really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.divclass > .elementclass
```